# What happened to "com.jfrog.artifactory-upload"?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

As of today, suddenly all my build.gradle files that contain:

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory-upload'
```

suddenly stopped working? What happened? Why?

The specific error message was:

```
Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.artifactory-upload' not found.
```

And (some of) the stack trace was:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.artifactory-upload' not found.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware$apply.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific so to "not working" means?

Comment: Sure, does the above help?

Answer (score 9):

What's great about 4.0.0 is that you can use both Configurations and Publication in the same build script to collect your build artifacts. Till now you could only use one of the two, and you also had to choose a different plugin ID, depending on your choice, causing confusion for many users. You can still use version 3+ with the old ID. 
In any case, including major releases as the latest plugin version in your build scripts is not a good practice. You can however go for '4+', instead of '+' to keep getting the latest improvements automatically. The 'Set Me Up' snippet in Artifactory will be modified in the next release to support the above practice.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, earlier today, jFrog decided to release [version 4.0.0](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory/4.0.0) of their plugin, and thought it was a neat idea for the new plugin, in [their words](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/blob/master/gradle-examples/README.md), to have "removed the com.jfrog.artifactory-upload plugin ID, leaving only one plugin ID: com.jfrog.artifactory".

(edit: and in [at least one place](http://subversion.jfrog.org/artifactory/public/trunk/web/application/src/main/resources/build.gradle.template), jFrog encouraged people to use "+" (i.e. most recent version) in specifying the plugin version. Happily, they don't seem to be doing that in most of the other places they give examples any more.)

(2nd edit: also, inside Artifactory's "Set Me Up" tool, the snippets it generates use "+")

Comment: You're right. We finally got rid of the two plugins in favor of one that works both with `configurations` and `publications`. And no, we never encourage people to use the latest version. Actually, [that's something we explicitly advice against](https://speakerdeck.com/jbaruch/using-software-modules-welcome-to-hell?slide=105).
The snippet you found is used in the "Set Me Up" and need to be fixed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: "Set Me Up" snippet fixed to use a concrete version.